# What is a roman numeral analysis of the chords from Coldplay's "God put a smile upon your face"?

Tags: harmony, chord-progressions, roman-numerals

I'm trying to apply Roman numeral analysis to some pop songs and am a little stumped on Coldplay's "God put a smile upon your face".

The chords, as I understand them, are:

Section A: 
D♭, E6, E♭7, Dmaj7

Section B: Amaj7, E6, F♯add9

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question does not conform to the title: You are not asking about _underlying harmonic analysis_  - you're simply asking for the chords to the song. That is not _underlying harmonic analysis_. Unfortunately, it is also off topic on this site. If you google for the chords to the song, more than likely you'll find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In some cases, Roman numerals aren't all that helpful, and this piece might be one of them.

In my opinion, Section A is best understood by considering two simultaneous actions:

1. The chromatic descent in the bass from E, through E♭ and D, to the tonic D♭.
2. And the constant presence of the tonic D♭ in all four of the chords. The D♭ is obviously the root of D♭, it's the 6 of E6 (spelled as C♯), the 7 of E♭7, and the maj7 (again spelled as C♯) of Dmaj7.

These two aspects make it *very* clear that D♭ is tonic, and that's ultimately what drives the harmonic motion: tension and resolution to that D♭.

The B Section is less clear, but there are two things to consider: B Sections often go somewhere else tonally, and here it seems to be rooted in A, which is enharmonic to ♭VI (B♭♭), a relatively common move dating back almost two centuries. Note also that the overall tonic D♭ is still present in every single chord, though now always spelled as C♯: it's the third of Amaj7, the sixth of E6, and the fifth of F♯add9.

In other words, Coldplay makes clear what the tonic is *by playing it in every single chord of the song*. If you try to sing a D♭ throughout the song, you'll see that it fits everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

I tried listening to the song and the progression in the A section is pretty non-functional which means there are going to be some ambiguities when doing the analysis.
The B section sounds like I-V-VI-I in the key of A (I'm not sure about the tensions, but if you're right then Imaj7-V6-VIadd9).
If I'm hearing it right each chord in the A section is played on the guitar by moving the open C chord shape around but leaving the open stings open, so each chord has an E and G though I think you got the basic movement down. We could interpret this section to also be in the key of A as III#9#11-V#9-bVb9-IVadd11 with the G and/or E providing the tensions on each, but I think you could make an argument for analyzing this in Db/C# since during the verse the bass is alternating between B and C# throughout. Either way there are many non-diatonic tones throughout. I like the interpretation in A since the III chord could be thought of as a sort of substitute for the I.